# Python not recognising Django Installation. (ImportError: No module named django)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am having a problem with installing Django. It seems that Python will not recognize it once it is installed. Below are the steps I have taken. I'm using Mac OS 10.7.5 Python 2.7 and Django 1.5.1

I am not using virtualenv

What am I doing wrong? Is there any reason Python will not recognize it? How can I fix this?

Here's what I've done:

uninstalled it, (with pip)

```
Successfully uninstalled Django
```

checked that is uninstalled (via yolk)

```
localhost:mysite brendan$ yolk -l
Flask-SQLAlchemy - 0.16         - active 
Flask           - 0.10.1       - active 
Jinja2          - 2.7          - active 
MarkupSafe      - 0.18         - active 
Python          - 2.7          - active development (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
SQLAlchemy      - 0.8.2        - active 
Werkzeug        - 0.9.1        - active 
boto            - 2.9.7        - active 
itsdangerous    - 0.22         - active 
nose            - 1.3.0        - active 
pip             - 1.3.1        - active 
setuptools      - 0.8          - active 
tweepy          - 1.7.1        - non-active 
tweepy          - 1.9          - active 
virtualenv      - 1.9.1        - active 
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7)
yolk            - 0.4.3        - active
```

installed it, (with pip)

```
localhost:mysite brendan$ pip install django
Downloading/unpacking django
Downloading Django-1.5.1.tar.gz (8.0MB): 8.0MB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package django

warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
Installing collected packages: django
Running setup.py install for django
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/django-admin.py from 644 to 755

warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
changing mode of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/django-admin.py to 755
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...

localhost:mysite brendan$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 19 2013, 13:26:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And I'm getting this error when trying to import:

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>>
```

**EDIT / UPDATES:**

which pip

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

which python

```
/opt/local/bin/python
```

I am not using virtualenv

Comment: what's the result of `which pip` and `which python`?

Comment: Are you utilizing a virtual environment?

Comment: Did you install another python outside of the system python?  That isn't the system python path.  It is possible that your pip is working with your system python and Django was installed on that

Comment: @sedavidw It is possible, I dont fully understand Pythonpaths. So my Python 2.7 which is installed in /opt/local/Library should be in /Library ????

Comment: @PaulRenton I have edited the question to reflect that I am not using a virtual environment, sorry i should have added that initially

Comment: @Deepend, that's not necessarily where it should be, you just need to know which python pip is installing to.  This is actually why virtualenv are so helpful.  When you make a virtualenv you can specify which python for it to use, and when you install any libraries after that you know they are going to that python without affecting any other python installs.  If possible I'd start a virutalenv and that points to your `/opt/local/bin/python` install and add libraries to that.  This is a good ref http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-virtualenv-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion-10.8/

Comment: Try using a virtual environment and install python while using it. I would bet that would fix your issue

Comment: @sedavidw You put me on the right path, I actually reinstalled Python from scratch. It is now located at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python and pip is now located at /usr/local/bin/pip Almost the opposite of my previous instillation. If you write your suggestions up in the form of an answer I will accept it. Paul Renton. I will look into that now. Thanks

Comment: @Deepend glad it worked out, I wrote up my answer

Comment: use `which python` to know your python version. See if django is installed for the same python you are using by typing `python -m django --version`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that your pip installation is pointing to a different python than your python version installed at `opt/local/bin/python`.  It is likely that your `pip` is talking to the system installed python and not the version you installed.

You can consider uninstalling python and re-installing in the correct path or creating a virtualenv that points to the version of python you desire.  Then any subsequent installs will point to the correct version of python without affecting other python installs

Answer (score 4):

try using pip as the superuser :

```
sudo pip install -U django
```

worked for me ...

Comment: What about updating pip ? sudo pip install -U pip ? and updating django sudo pip install -U django ?

Comment: I have updated pip but it has no effect, I don't believe it is a problem with the instillation of Django but rather where it is being installed or where my Python is that it is not finding it

Comment: this worked for me. I still don't get what this does, but without the "-U", i had the import error.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer was correct. The solution does not require reinstall python.  Best practice to use virtalenv. On the mac, 'pip' will reference python2 by default, to use python3's pip the command is 'pip3' or 'pip3.4'.   In the current virtualenv, use 'pip list' or 'pip3 list' to display all installed modules, if django is not install then 'pip install django'.

Comment: hey, can you help me out here. My problem is little off topic. When i do `pip3` or `pip3.4` it says `command not found`. Please help me here